# Responsive Web Page: Prevent desktop version Image from being download on mobile resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

On my HTML/PHP page, I first have the Mobile HTML Block, which is hidden on desktop resolutions, and then the Desktop HTML block, which is hidden on the opposite mobile resolution:

```
<div class="mobile-version">
    <img src="/images/300.jpg">
</div>  

<div class="desktop-version">
    <img src="/images/90.jpg">
</div>
```

I'm trying to improve my Google Page speed score, so I don't want to load the `90.jpg` if the user is on Mobile screen width.

However, if I just use `style="display:none"`, I can see in chrome dev. tools that the image is still being loaded by browser.

How to handle this?

Comment: display none will just prevent the image from being displayed, not loaded. You should work with media queries and load images depending on the media query applied

Comment: @LelioFaieta but this is exactly what I'm asking, how to "Load" an image depending on CSS media query? what is the correct CSS property?

Answer (score 0):

The dom is interpreted before the application of any css. At this stage, I see two solutions :

> Lazy loading : this will require javascript; you can inject src tags only on the elements that are not effictively hidden.

> Html 5 picture element : this HTML5 element contains the  and the  tag. The advantage is that you can apply a media filter in the source element, so only loaded on desktop devices. The only thing that will be always loaded is the fallback img src, but this is less problematic.

Comment: First time I hear of this picture element. is this a good practice?